# Shared Printer installation in Win7 64bit

Tags: windows-7

we have a network shared HP P2035n laser jet printer connected to a XP computer, the shared printer users are using window 7 32bit platform. my manager brought a new Sony Vaio Laptop which is running on win7 64bit. i tried to connect the shared printer on his but, it started searching for windows update & gave a error massage drivers not found. How can i connect this printer to his pc..

Comment: why would you stick win7 pcs behind an XP device to print?

Comment: THIS WAS ALREADY DONE,WHEN I JOIN HERE..I CAN'T CHANGE THE PLAN..NOW

Comment: @DejaWood [SF] is for Profession System Administrators only. This question will be moved to our sister site [SU], which is for casual and more advanced users like yourself.

Answer (score 2):

In the printer settings on the windows xp computer go into sharing tab and click additional drivers. Install the  X64 driver there and reinstall on the laptop via the share. You will need to download the X64 driver off the HP website.

Comment: brother printer cd got miss placed..is there anyways to install the additional drivers for printer direct connected PC...

Comment: In your question you said it was a HP. If you go to the manufactures website they will have the drivers in a downloads section. If you can clarify the model if it is a HP or a brother I'll take a look for you.

Comment: thank you..it's a HP P2035n printer..i checked Hp site for drivers..& i got the windows 7 64bit drivers. you want me to install this in XP PC, which is directly connected.won't it be a problem..or is there any way to install this.

Comment: You need to install it as an addional driver as above and it wont affect the Main driver.

Comment: K..IT HAS TO BE INSTALL AS AN ADDITIONAL DRIVER..IF YOU TRY TO INSTALL IN THAT WAY..IT IS ASKING FOR AN .INF FILE, WHICH IS NOT THERE..HOW CAN I FIND THAT FILE..I SEARCHED IN GOOGLE..BUT I COULDN'T..PLZZ HELP..